# Given two iterators to the same data structure, how to check which iterator is before the other?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, containers

Given a function such as the following:

```
template<typename ForwardIterator>
void MyFunc(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last) {
...
}
```

Given that `first` and `last` are in the same data structure, how can I check that `first` is in fact before `last` in this data structure?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of solving this problem, just do what the standard library does: Assert the precondition that last must be reachable from first and be done (note that it may be reachable by identity).

If you don't make that precondition you *have* to also be given a reference/pointer to the container, or the `begin`/`end` of the container in order to do the validation checks.

Comment: @amigo421 Put in your function's documentation that it's the callers responsibility to ensure the iterators are in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

just use std::distance with someContainer.begin() as argument:

```
auto d1 = std::distance(someContainer.begin() , iterator1);
auto d2 = std::distance(someContainer.begin() , iterator2);

if (d1>d2){..
```

Comment: how can I get the container itself?

Comment: @amigo421 You don't need to reference the container. You can just use two iterators with the function.

Comment: well, you didn't mention you don't hold the container itself. an iterator is a generalization of a pointer . can you tell if one pointer points to a 'farer' element then another one ? only if the container is contagious. if not , and you don't hold the container , I don't know any method of it

Comment: see the description from cppreference.com: 
The behavior is undefined if last is not reachable from first by (possibly repeatedly) incrementing first. that is exactly what I want to check - that first < last is ok. but in case if I get function parameters last < first there will undefined behavior, isnot it?

Comment: @amigo421 As far as I know it's not possible, given two arbitrary iterators, to tell if they are in the same data structure of not.

Comment: I can guarantee they are in the same container but can't guarantee the right order of them

Comment: @amigo421 Then you could accept a third iterator to the beginning of the container, and use `distance` to perform the check. If you don't want to do that then document what the function expects and rely on the caller to not screw up, this is what practically every algorithm taking iterators does.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "in general, you can't".

The longer answer is: You can increment `first` over and over again, and if you get to `last`, then you know that first was "before" last. If you don't get to `last`, well, maybe you haven't gone far enough - there's no way to tell.

As Mark B says in his answer, the way the standard library does it is to tell the user "It's your responsibility to make sure that `last` is reachable from `first`".